# Orange: Data has no target variable error

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, random-forest, orange, csv

I am trying to apply **Random Forest** algorithm on a data set using Orange. The target variable is not set in the data set. However, I know which column is the target variable.

How can I specify the target variable in a **.csv** file using **Orange** or any other tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the target by choosing target in the feature column

[image]